# Stuck between "Is Library" and "cannot creake *.apk file"

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

The problem is I copied the tutorial from http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/google-maps-android-api-v2-mylocation-locationsource-and-event-handling/. I have imported the google-play-services-library in my project. I have selected both my project and the library as "Is Library". The problem is if I uncheck my project as "Is Library" it won't compile and says it has errors. And if I check it and then run it, the myproject.apk files isn't created at all.
I am stuck! Please help! What should I do?

PS: I encountered this problem after I signed the release key for my project because the maps wouldn't work simply on debugkey. I had to have the releasekey!.

I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: Your application should not be marked as a library unless it is a library. Those errors are probably trying to tell you something. What do they say?

Comment: If I uncheck my project as "Is Library", the error says "There are errors in your project"

Comment: And right now I created a new project and the same error occurred "Your project contains errors! Please fix them before running your application"

Comment: And what are those errors? You should be able to find more information on those errors. In Eclipse, go to Window > Show View > Problems.

Comment: Error generating final archive: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

Comment: What does it mean? Sorry I am a total newbie to android.

Comment: Well that error seems indicate that there is a problem with your keystore. Assuming that you are using the default debug keystore (Window > Preferences > Android > Build) and not a custom debug keystore, I'm not sure why that would happen. Perhaps try installing a clean copy of Eclipse and the SDK?

Comment: I deleted the old debug keystore and it worked for me.